# Is there a word for something that has been slowly intensifying, and has now reached a degree that needs attention

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to write an article where I am talking about a phenomenon that has been creeping in the background, and has now reached epic proportions that deserves immediate attention. For example, I'd like a positive word (so not "a mounting problem") for saying this concisely: We must start deploying efficient rainwater harvesting solutions now, **given the increasing degree of water scarcity**. I'm pretty sure there's a word for it, but I couldn't find it using a thesaurus. A concise phrase would be the next best thing.

Comment: As with all one-word requests, a sample sentence is needed which demonstrates how your word would be used in context.

Comment: ‘Increasing degree of scarcity’ should definitely be avoided unless the tone in general is humorous. It makes the reader do an unnecessary semantic double-take.

Comment: Avoid posting word or phrase requests without: (i) your criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: @NigelJ I have provided an example sentence. Does that not suffice? I held back from putting the actual sentence, as the article is a neuroscience paper with quite a few distracting academic terms.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the scientific term “Critical point” in a literary way to describe the moments in which a paradigm shift or significant change occurs.

> **critical point**
>   noun/
>
> *Physics* The point at which a substance in one phase, as the liquid, has the same density, pressure, and temperature as in another phase, as the gaseous.
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/critical-point)

Comment: ... And if you say "has reached a critical point," it also implies prior escalation over time.

Answer (score 2):

You might say that water scarcity has crossed a ***[threshold](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/threshold)***:

> 3b : a level, point, or value above which something is true or will take place and below which it is not or will not
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/threshold)*</sub>

Alternatively, water scarcity may be approaching, or may have already reached or crossed a ***[tipping point](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tipping%20point)***:

> : the critical point in a situation, process, or system beyond which a significant and often unstoppable effect or change takes place
>   <sub>*also from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tipping%20point)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Come to a head.

From Cambridge University Press Dictionary: Reach a point where some strong action must be taken.

Answer (score -1):

Endemic may apply in your example. "We must start deploying efficient rainwater harvesting solutions now, given the endemic drought.

Answer (score -2):

tipping point or boiling point

Comment: These suggestions are a good beginning but really need definitions and cited sources to be a complete answer.